# jquery on change function with bootstrap modal in while loop

Tags: php, jquery

i have this simple php code with two buttons to open a bootstrap modal in a while loop

The modals are currently working but the jquery script on change function is working only  on the first modal but not in the second modal

How do i modify the on change jquery script so that it will work in both modals ?

Thank you

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#level').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#level1").show();
        $("#level2").hide();
      }
       else if ( this.value == '2')
      { 
       $("#level1").hide();
        $("#level2").show();  
      }
      else
      {

      }
    });
});
</script>


  <?php
  $x = 1; 

while($x <= 2) {

echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal$x' data-id='$x' id='$x'>Open Modal $x</button><br />";


?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal<?php echo $x?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

     <?php echo $x; ?>
       <div class='form-group'>
<label for='level'> Please select level:</label>
<select class='form-control' id='level' name='level'>
<option value=''>Select</option>
<option value='1'>Level 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Level 2</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div style='display:none;' id='level1'>
 This is Level 1
</div>

<div style='display:none;' id='level2'>
This is Level 2
</div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<?php
  $x++;
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check for all id starting with the name `level` thanks to `$('[id^=level]')`. I also add a unique value to id level like `id='level<?php echo $x; ?>'`. An id must be unique.

Full code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=level]').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
        if ( this.value == '1'){
            $("[id^=level1_txt"+id+"]").show();
            $("[id^=level2_txt"+id+"]").hide();
        }else if ( this.value == '2'){ 
            $("[id^=level1_txt"+id+"]").hide();
            $("[id^=level2_txt"+id+"]").show();  
        }else{
            //Hide when not selected
            //$("[id^=level1_txt]").hide();
            //$("[id^=level2_txt]").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>


<?php
$x = 1; 
while($x <= 2) {
    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal$x' data-id='$x' id='$x'>Open Modal $x</button><br />";
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal<?php echo $x?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo $x; ?>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='level<?php echo $x; ?>'> Please select level:</label>
            <select class='form-control' id='level<?php echo $x; ?>' name='level'>
                <option value=''>Select</option>
                <option value='1'>Level 1</option>
                <option value='2'>Level 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style='display:none;' id='level1_txt<?php echo $x; ?>'>
            This is Level 1
        </div>
        <div style='display:none;' id='level2_txt<?php echo $x; ?>'>
            This is Level 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php
    $x++;
} 

?>
```

Comment: thank you but i tried the code above but not working

Comment: still not working properly... when i open the second modal level 2 is  pre-selected without selection

Answer (score 0):

It is working only with the first modal because you used **id**, and you have to know that ID are supposed to be **uniques**, so jQuery will attach your listener on the first `<select>` only, and will show and hide only your first `#levelX`.

Try updating your code with **classes** instead of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in code please check and let me know if you are still getting the issue.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#level').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#level1").show();
        $("#level2").hide();
      }
       else if ( this.value == '2')
      { 
       $("#level1").hide();
        $("#level2").show();  
      }
      else
      {

      }
    });

    $('.open-modal').on('click', function() {
        const index = $(this).data('index);
      $("#myModal"+index).show();
      $(this).find("#level1").hide();
      $(this).find("#level2").hide();
    });
});
</script>


<?php
$x = 1;
while($x <= 2) {

    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info open-modal' data-index='".$x."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal$x' data-id='$x' id='$x'>Open Modal $x</button><br />";


    ?>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal<?php echo $x?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <?php echo $x; ?>
        <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='level'> Please select level:</label>
    <select class='form-control' id='level' name='level'>
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='1'>Level 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Level 2</option>
    </select>

    </div>

    <div style='display:none;' id='level1'>
    This is Level 1
    </div>

    <div style='display:none;' id='level2'>
    This is Level 2
    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <?php
  $x++;
} 

?>
```